# Hyperplane arrangements and tropical linear spaces

Tags: matroid-theory, tropical-geometry, hyperplane-arrangements

I have been trying to understand Chapter 5.4 of this [Brief Introduction to Tropical Geometry](https://gokovagt.org/proceedings/2014/ggt14-brugitenmikhshaw.pdf), but I am struggling because of my lack of mathematical background. I will ask a few questions after giving some background, and I would appreciate hints or answers to any one of these. I have some background in Projective Geometry.

> [image]

1. I understand algebraically how the hyperplane arrangement $\overline{\mathcal{L}}$ appears, but I struggle to visualize it. Is there a low dimensional example that can help me out?

> [image]

1. I don't quite understand how the stratification works.
2. I'm struggling to understand what $F_I$ looks like, along with the cone in the tropical limit.
3. I'm struggling to understand what a computation of this decomposition looks like. I tried to follow along with this example:

> [image]

but could not reproduce the Peterson graph. Lastly, I don't think I completely understand this "simpler" example either:

> [image]
> [image: Blockquote]

I know these are a lot of questions, but just helping me understand a little bit of it would be greatly appreciated. I really want to understand this!

(There is this paper by [Gatthman](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.2268.pdf) that may help, but I haven't had a chance to look at it yet.)